# How can I have multiple forms/dialogs open and allow input to all concurrently?

Tags: vb.net

When I have my main form open, and I show a dialog I cannot provide input to the main form until the dialog is closed. I was looking to create a heads up display (HUD), and I need a dialog box in the corner displaying output. I need my main form open for input. However, my dialog box is preventing me from interacting with my main form.

I wish I could come up with a better title, but I didn't know what to call this question.

Comment: How are you displaying your "dialog"?  You can certainly have more than one `Form` open.  Whichever one is focused would be receiving input, but the others can still be updated from code.

Comment: I would display it by HUD.ShowDialog()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using [`Form.ShowDialog()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx) then your forms are, by design, modal.  "Modal" means that the form needs to be closed before the form which launched it can receive input.  If instead you use [`Form.Show()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.show(v=vs.110).aspx) then the form is not modal by default and would allow the previous form to be focused without having to close the new form.

Basically, if you don't want your forms to be modal dialogs, don't use `ShowDialog()`.

Comment: Ah, I see now. If I use a button to do HUD.Show(), it works. However, in my main Form's Load statement, my dialog won't show up.

Edit: Wait, never mind, it worked. The dialog appeared behind my form and somehow I wasn't smart enough to notice. My apologizes.